# How to play admob ads in a video player but NOT as full screen?

Tags: react-native, google-chrome, video, admob, ads

I'm developing an app with react native to deploy to iOS and Android. I have a video player in my app (looks similar to Youtube's UI when not in landscape mode).

Is there a way to play Google Admob ads in the video player without it going full screen? I want Admob ads to play in the same way ads play in the Youtube mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Admob's native video ads. This allows you to customise the look of the video ad.

More information here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/video-ads

Comment: Would this allow me to play ads automatically provided by Google admob? As a test case, I want to try playing these ads continuously (at random) one after another without my input. 

From there I want to have them play between custom videos but that’s later down the road.